# Lightning Internal Server Error Caused By Changing Return Type

Tags: apex, lightning, gack

I've got an Apex controller method that returns a `List<ReportLine>` where `ReportLine` is a pretty simple custom class.

```
public class ReportLine
{
    @auraEnabled
    public String Name {get; set;}

    @auraEnabled
    public User UserInfo {get; set;}

    @auraEnabled
    public String Id {get; set;}

    @auraEnabled
    public Integer Sent {get; set;}

    @auraEnabled
    public Integer Opened {get; set;}

    @auraEnabled
    public Integer Replies {get; set;}

    @auraEnabled
    public Decimal AttributedSales {get; set;}

    public ReportLine()
    {
        Sent = 0;
        Opened = 0;
        Replies = 0;
        AttributedSales = 0.0;
    }
}
```

I want to change that method to return a wrapper class that includes the old `List<ReportLine>` value, but the moment I change the return type to the following wrapper class, I get an internal server error.

```
public class ReportData
{
    @auraEnabled
    public Map<Date, ReportLine> dailyTotals {get; set;}

    @auraEnabled
    public List<ReportLine> linesByEntity {get; set;}
}
```

Am I missing something obvious? Can you not return a type that's composed of another custom type? This is a pretty sub-standard development experience. I've tried wrapping the entire method body inside of a try/catch block to see if there was an exception being thrown, but it definitely appears to be related to the return type.

## Edit

I suspect this is something particular to my org getting into a funky state somewhere. I've just stripped the Apex controller class down to this and I'm still getting the error:

```
public with sharing class OutreachReportServices
{
    public class ReportData
    {
        @auraEnabled
        public List<String> dailyTotals {get; set;}

        @auraEnabled
        public List<String> linesByEntity {get; set;}
    }

    @auraEnabled
    public static ReportData getLinesByStore(String type, Date rangeStart, Date rangeEnd)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried adding @AuraEnabled to the class itself?

Comment: The apex class? Just gave it a go after your comment and same deal as if I try it on the custom classes: You can't use @auraEnabled on types.

Comment: Hmm. Well, I *have* used custom types, so I know it works. It's probably something obvious. What's the gack, maybe I can track it down?

Comment: Hmmm, it's 227057212 which appears to be this: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/146179/opening-lightning-application-with-not-enough-security-access-level-raises-inter#146180 But I've not changed anything to do with what the method does, just the type it's returning!

Comment: Hmm, okay, let me play with this. What's ReportLine look like?

Comment: I've added it, but as per my main edit, I think this is just a case of a certain proprietary black box platform striking again.

Comment: Isn't `Type` a reserved keyword? That should cause a compile fail. Although I too am able to compile a variable declared with that name. Still, changing it might fix the issue...

Comment: Tried changing it, no luck :(

Comment: I know Apex is not case-sensitive, but I haven't seen `@auraEnabled` beginning with a lower case. Maybe you could try `@AuraEnabled`.  `@AuraEnabled` enables client- and server-side access to the controller method.

Comment: @N.B. Figured at this point it was worth a shot, but no go :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well this might help somebody else, or it might not. Now that I know what's going on, it makes sense that the changing the return type was causing this issue. I'd neglected to notice (I set this code up a while ago) that the code I was modifying was in a services class, and *not* the Apex controller class that the Lightning controller was calling.

Changing this return type should have failed to save as it invalidated the other class, but for some reason it didn't, putting the other class into a broken state. Of course some logs to that effect would have been useful, but there was nothing in the front end or the dev console to suggest what was going on.